# JHipster v7.1.0: TLS support in dev not working - app crashes or throw exception

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I have created a simple microservice application, one gateway and one service, using JDL and enabling 'tls' in dev does not work out off the box, anyone know how to configure it in dev?

This are the only documentation that I have found about tls in JHipster and which I have followed:

- https://www.jhipster.tech/tls/
- https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security

These are the steps to reproduce the the exceptions I got when enabling 'tls' in dev;

1. Create a folder 'myapp' and move in to that folder.
2. Run: git init
3. Generate app: jhipster jdl model.jdl
4. npm install
5. mvn clean install
6. Move to the gateway folder (onegateway)
7. Start registry:

   docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml up -d
8. Start database:

   docker-compose -f src/main/docker/postgresql.yml up -d
9. Start up with both dev&tls profiles:

   ./mvnw -Pdev,tls

The app crashes with;

```
2021-08-11 14:32:29.069  WARN 83643 --- [  restartedMain] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set cipher suite: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
2021-08-11 14:32:29.115 ERROR 83643 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set cipher suite: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at com.carestra.jhipster.gateway.OnegatewayApp.main(OnegatewayApp.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set cipher suite: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:392)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.<init>(SslProvider.java:361)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$Build.build(SslProvider.java:734)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer.secure(HttpServer.java:721)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer.secure(HttpServer.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.SslServerCustomizer.apply(SslServerCustomizer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.customizeSslConfiguration(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.createHttpServer(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.getWebServer(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager.<init>(WebServerManager.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:78)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failed to set cipher suite: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslContext.<init>(OpenSslContext.java:45)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:473)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:606)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.AbstractProtocolSslContextSpec.sslContext(AbstractProtocolSslContextSpec.java:53)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.<init>(SslProvider.java:358)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.CipherSuiteConverter.convertToCipherStrings(CipherSuiteConverter.java:470)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:282)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

##########
All ciphers are those generated by jhipster and also found in https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security

If I remove the cipher in, **onegateway/src/main/resources/config/application-tls.yml** the app starts but I get the following when accessing **https://localhost:8080**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'onegateway' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      https://localhost:8080/
    External:   https://192.168.50.11:8080/
    Profile(s):     [dev, api-docs, tls]
----------------------------------------------------------
2021-08-11 14:18:36.554  WARN 83547 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler : [id: 0x3b06913a, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61605] Failed to select the application-level protocol:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000416:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.shutdownWithError(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1064)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1346)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1371)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1414)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:224)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2021-08-11 14:18:36.558  WARN 83547 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler : [id: 0x3b06913a, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 ! R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61605] TLS handshake failed:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000416:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.shutdownWithError(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1064)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1346)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1371)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1414)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:224)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

###################

I have also tried reverting all prev changes to application-tls.yml and activate tls for dev profile in **src/main/resources/config/application.yml** by uncomment the property: **spring.profiles.group.dev.tls** and starting the app with

```
./mvnw -Pdev
```

Got the same problem with unsupported cipher suite.

#########################

This is my **model.jdl**

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType gateway,
    baseName onegateway,
    packageName com.carestra.jhipster.gateway,
    authenticationType jwt,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    buildTool maven,
    reactive true,
    skipClient false,
    skipServer false,
    skipUserManagement false,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    clientFramework angularX,
    testFrameworks [cypress],
    enableTranslation true,
    nativeLanguage en,
    languages [en]
  }

  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    applicationType microservice,
    baseName onebackend,
    packageName com.carestra.jhipster.backend,
    authenticationType jwt,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    buildTool maven,
    reactive false,
    skipClient true,
    skipUserManagement true,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    devDatabaseType postgresql,
    testFrameworks [cypress]
  }

  entities *
}

entity Activity {
    id Long,
    title String minlength(4) maxlength(50) required,
    startDate Instant required,
    endDate Instant required,
}

entity Booking {
    id Long,
    activityId Long required,
    message String minlength(0) maxlength(500),
}

microservice * with onebackend

deployment {
  deploymentType docker-compose
  appsFolders [onegateway, onebackend]
  dockerRepositoryName "carestra"
  serviceDiscoveryType eureka
}
```

and the **.yo-rc.json**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "withAdminUi": true,
    "baseName": "onegateway",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "languages": ["en"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "skipClient": false,
    "testFrameworks": ["cypress"],
    "websocket": false,
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "packageName": "com.carestra.jhipster.gateway",
    "packageFolder": "com/carestra/jhipster/gateway",
    "reactive": true,
    "skipServer": false,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.1.0",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "applicationIndex": 0,
    "applications": {
      "onebackend": {
        "serverPort": "8081",
        "applicationIndex": 1
      }
    },
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "blueprints": [],
    "otherModules": [],
    "pages": [],
    "creationTimestamp": 1628675597074,
    "jwtSecretKey": "NDE5ZTFkOTJiYzQ1ZGI5NmZlMmZjNWQ5NzVjZTkwODJhZWJjMTFlZjQ5NjcwOWU5MWI1NjdiNWI4MjBlNmY5ODFkNThhNzk4NjllNzA2MWM1N2YzOTdhMjdhNTcyY2ZhZDk5ODM1MjU4ODJhM2YxYTMzYTM2ZTNlNWM5N2UxOWU=",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "entities": ["Booking", "Activity"],
    "lastLiquibaseTimestamp": 1628675717000
  }
}
```

and

###### **Environment and Tools**

openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

git version 2.23.0

node: v14.17.3

npm: 7.20.1

Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

Comment: Using curl, I got:
`>curl http://localhost:8080 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`
and `>curl https://localhost:8080
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`

So I clicked "NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID" when accessing from the browser and save the cert to a file (certfile.cert). Run again with `curl --cacert certfile.cert https://localhost:8080` and got a response back. It says I need to start "npm start" but according to the docs I need to start "npm run start-tls". Did not work got Unknown option: '--env.tls'

Comment: Found issues when starting 'npm run start-tls' and using angular, https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/15655 and this may also be relevant since using reactive https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14415

Answer (score 1):

I commented on one issue, also.  Here's what I did as a workaround:
In `package.json`
replace

```
"start-tls": "npm run webapp:dev -- --env.tls",
```

with

```
"start-tls": "npm run webapp:dev -- --env tls",
```

For the dev profile, the options.tls variable is checked whether it's set, and if so, the "s" is appended to http.  But I don't know my way around webpack and javascript stuff at all, so not sure, yet, what other implications there are.